# Можно более понятно выразить мысль, которая кажется не вполне ясной?

Tags: грамотная-речь, стилистика, семантика

Отрывок из школьного сочинения:

*Делать добро, для того чтобы твоя жизнь, приносила радость и делала твою жизнь счастливой, от этого **ты меняешься, как человек и делаешься твердым и смелым в жизни.***

Школьники пишут сочинения… Они не всегда умеют точно выразить свою мысль, допускают повторы, стилевые ошибки. В то же время подкупает их искренность – эти сочинения уж точно ниоткуда не списаны. Вот и здесь такой пример.

Меня же заинтересовала **само суждение:** как добро может сделать человека смелым и твердым. Разве есть здесь какая-то связь?

Можно ли отредактировать предложение так, чтобы смысл сказанного был понятен?

Comment: Как можно говорить об искренности в школьном сочинении, когда их заставляют писать эти работы? Дети пишут то, что от них требуют учителя. Всегда нужно хвалить автора, соглашаться с ним, выхваливать вещи и темы, которые могут быть ребёнку безразличны. Суждения эти пишутся "на отвали", часто без осмысления. Там и поэзия, и книги "сделают человека смелым", лишь бы скорее сдать задание и домой пойти. А искренность — в комментариях в интернете, вот они точно ниоткуда не списаны.

Comment: Может быть и так.  Понятны стандартные мысли, которые учитель заставляет писать. Но какое отношение к доброте имеют  смелость и твердость? Вы их можете  как-то связать и красиво записать?

Comment: Детей же учат, что добро побеждает зло, то есть что оно сильнее. Так вот и дофантазировали, что добро делает человека сильным — твёрдым и смелым, как добрый рыцарь.

Comment: oleedd, ответьте, пожалуйста , не в комментариях, а то как я вам зачет поставлю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Детей же учат, что добро побеждает зло, то есть что оно сильнее. Так вот и дофантазировали, что добро делает человека сильным — твёрдым и смелым, как добрый рыцарь.

Ещё учат (также через сказки, рассказы), что зло — трусость (например, злой и трусливый персонаж), а добро получается антонимом — смелостью. В пример можно привести добрых, сильных и смелых богатырей. Их сила в смелости и твёрдости духа.

Но в реальности на доброте часто выезжают, пользуются ею, вместо того чтобы ценить. Также часто злые люди оказываются более сильными, чем добрые. То есть сказка и реальность идут порознь.

Более понятно:
*Делай добро, чтобы жизнь твоя приносила радость и счастье — не только тебе, но и всем вокруг, — это меняет человека: делает его твердым и смелым по жизни.*

> Можно более понятно выразить мысль, которая кажется не вполне ясной?

Ясность мысли вопросов не вызывает, но вопросы к её достоверности.

Comment: oleedd, мне показалась интересной ваша мысль, и я попробовала выразить ее своими словами.

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, что тут есть логика: делая добрые поступки, человек помогает сам себе, ему воздастся сторицею за это, если он делает это не ради награды. А когда он на верном пути, он обретает уверенность в себе и смелость. В хорошем смысле, не нахальность, конечно. Я бы переформулировал так:

*Стоит делать добро, чтобы жизнь приносила тебе радость и становилась счастливой. От этого твоя натура меняется, ты твёрже и смелее идёшь по жизни.*

Comment: Спасибо за ваше мнение, отвечу завтра.

Comment: Спасибо, Артем, все-таки сам переход к обретению уверенности и смелости остался для меня не совсем ясен.

Comment: Жалко, что не поняли. Не знаю даже, как объяснить...

Comment: Ах, Артем, не вижу однозначных связей.  Добро, конечно, приносит радость, но точно ли всегда? Будешь ли ты добрым и при этом гарантированно счастливым?  Внутренний мир, безусловно, меняется, но разве смелость, сила воли прибавятся непременно?  Волю укрепляет деятельное и активное добро,  но отнюдь не каждое. Но это мое мнение.  В сочинении же важны ясные логические связи. Если борешься со злом и защищаешь добро, вот ты и смелый рыцарь!  Помните у Окуджавы: Ах, не делайте запаса из любви и доброты, и про черный день грядущий не копите милосердья. Это призыв к активному добру.

Comment: Да, согласен, что тут много факторов влияет, всё сложно. Но хотя бы иногда это работает, как я описал, imho.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы ответила так:

Нужно не просто ощущать себя добрым, **а делать добрые дела** – вот что важно. Это те поступки, которые требуют **от нас усилий**,  преодоления материи, которая сама по себе ни добрая и не злая, но вязкая и расположенная к сопротивлению.

Делая людям добро, мы как бы создаем (творим!) его сами. И  вот что удивительно – становимся при этом лучше.  Потому что понимаем, что можем противодействовать тем силам, которые  сопротивляются всему светлому и любящему.

**Мы походим через  трудности**, решаем конкретные задачи  и от этого становимся **сильнее и увереннее.** Люди благодарят нас, а мы благодарны им.